# Jasmine won't load javascript files from asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, jasmine, assets

I'm developing a gem and I've installed Jasmine https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem/

All of my required JS files are in my manifest file at app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require underscore
//= require backbone

//= require_tree .//vendor
//= require_tree .//custom

//= require_tree .//templates
//= require_tree .//models
//= require_tree .//collections
//= require_tree .//views
```

And my jasmine.yml file references that:

```
src_files:
  - 'app/assets/javascripts/application.js'
```

But none of the files specified in it load. Anyone know why? I'm using the latest, Jasmine 1.3.2, which is supposed to support the asset pipeline so that you don't need to use something like jasmine-rails. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your jasmine.yml the path should be 'assets/application.js'. If you're still having trouble, make sure you have your jasmine gem under both development and test groups in your Gemfile, as specified in the instructions on https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'jasmine'
end
```

Comment: I did exactly this, but assets are still not loaded. I have "//= require underscore" in my application.js, and "src_files:
  - assets/application.js" in jasmine.yml, but when I call a function in underscore.js, I am told it's not defined. The problem goes away only if I have "  - assets/underscore.js" under 'src_files' in jasmine.yml. Super frustrating.

Comment: Turns out assets are not being compiled. I fixed the problem by uncommenting the therubyracer line in Gemfile. But in another app - where Ruby version is 1.9.3p194 - I didn't need to do this (in the current app Ruby version is 2.0.0p247). Still somewhat a puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails 4 there is bug in version 1.3.2 where is it checking `config.assets.enabled` which no longer is defined in Rails 4.

The following worked for me.
`gem 'jasmine', "~> 2.0.0.rc4"`

This is the ticket that talks about the issue. https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem/pull/177